# Крокозябры при вводе параметров на русском netbeans web-service

Tags: java, netbeans, кириллица, веб-служба

В netbeans создал веб службу которая принимает входящие параметры, например ФИО, Иванов Иван Иванович, но при тестировании веб-службы кириллица отображается неверно  - 'ÐÐ²Ð°Ð½Ð¾Ð² ÐÐ²Ð°Ð½ ÐÐ²Ð°Ð½Ð¾Ð²Ð¸Ñ' кодировка везде UTF-8 думаю, что при генерации страницы тестера на которой вводишь параметры не та кодировка т.е. она вообще не указана. Может кто сталкивался с такой проблемой? буду рад любой помощи!))

Comment: Как вы тестируете?Локальный сервер/через тестовые методы/еще как-то? Как вы выводите тест (в консоль/на страницу/в файл) ?

Comment: Может быть поможет установка кодировки по умолчанию в веб-приложении? Для каждого сервера по-разному. Для wildfly в `jboss-web.xml` должно быть `<default-encoding>UTF-8</default-encoding>` В `glassfish-web.xml` (если у Вас glassfish) должно быть `<parameter-encoding default-charset="UTF-8"/>`. Restfull службы или обычные, SOAP?

Comment: @Dred на локальном, тест вывожу на страницу в хроме. Страница Web Service Tester - генерируется нетбинсом, при просмотре кода страницы НЕ указана кодировка тут и проблема может

Comment: Напишите фильтр. Недавно тут решили эту проблему